# Crystal Reports distinguish preview and print for pre-printed form printing in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, crystal-reports

I have developed the asp.net application in c# and I am using Crystal Reports 13.

I have requirement like some report I have pre-printed page. So when view the report it display the reports include the logo and border but when I click on print button it suppress the logo and border which are already in the pre-printed paper.

Comment: Just for clarification: You do not want the logo and border printed?

Comment: yes i need to suppress or hide the logo and border

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant way, but the only way I have been able to make it work:

1. Create a paramter (call it PrintOption) and set the default value to "False".
2. For every field you want to suppress, right-click on the field and click "Format Field"
3. In the Common tab for the field enter a suppression formula ("x+2" symbol)
4. Enter `{?PrintOption} = True` and save.

Now when you run the report it will show logo's and borders and when you are about to print just change the parameter to True and it will suppress your logos and borders.

Comment: Hello I have tried to do the same but when i print/export parameter value is not refresh

Comment: Can  you please provide sample for this

Comment: You will just have to either run your report with the parameter as true or false depending on whether you want to see the logo and borders or not. And if you run it with logo and borders visible and then want to print it later you will have to refresh the report and set the parameter to True.

Comment: Hello , I did not understood  as i have used the refreshreport function of crystal report viewer asking for the parameter value. can you please provide me the sample